# What is in a block of memory after a kmalloc() call? kcalloc()?

Tags: c

I've found plenty of documentation on malloc and calloc, but the summary documentation on the kernel versions are woefully incomplete and unclear on this topic. I've been working under the assumption the kernel versions act the same, but I can't guarantee that.

Comment: `kcalloc` zeros the memory.  `kmalloc` makes no guarantees.

Comment: @TomKarzes so they are the same as `calloc` and `malloc`?

Comment: @JorgeMorgado No, they're kernel functions.  They're analogous, but different.